# C program: Implement depth first search (DFS) : Print the whole visiting sequence AND the different groups of disconnected components

Tags: c, matrix, depth-first-search

Here is my code.

I am using C program to implement depth first search (DFS)
the input will be a matrix and output will be to

1. Print the whole visiting sequence
2. Print the different groups of disconnected components

My code is able to print the first group of connected vertices but not for the remaining.
This code is also unable to print the whole visiting sequence.
Appreciate any help given thank you.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#define maxV 10

int count;
int G[maxV][maxV];
int visit[maxV];
int n; //number of vertices
int s; //starting point

void dfs(int v){
    count=count+1;
    int i;
    visit[v]=count;
    printf("%d->",v);

    for (i=1;i<n+1;i++){
        if (G[v][i]!=0 && visit[i]==0){
            dfs(i);
        }
    }
}

void main(){
    int i;
    int j;
    int count=0;


    printf("Enter number of vertices: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i=1;i<n+1;i++)
    {
        visit[i]=0;
    }

    printf("\nEnter adjecency matrix of the graph:");
    for(i=1;i<n+1;i++)
        for(j=1;j<n+1;j++)
            scanf("%d", &G[i][j]);

    printf("Enter starting vertix:");
    scanf("%d",&s);
    dfs(s);

    for (i=1;i<n+1;i++){
        if (visit[i])
            count=count+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by repairing *all* the indexing in this to use zero-based base indexing. You're programming in C now; stop fighting the inevitable. Second, *after* you do that, include in your question the exactly input data you're using when populating your posted code with a *reproducible* case.

Comment: Also indent your code properly and remove those useless blank lines. It's OK to have a blank line here and there, but too much is too much